# take mse from h2o performance and save it in a variable.

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o

I have a model in h2o(R). Its performance generates

```
h2o.performance(models[[1]],valid=T)
```

gives output

```
H2ORegressionMetrics: deeplearning
** Reported on validation data. **
Description: Metrics reported on temporary validation frame with 9724 samples

MSE:  1.18963
R2 :  0.07689513
Mean Residual Deviance :  1.18963
```

I want to take MSE and save it in a variable. i tried to generate confusion matrix using

```
 h2o.confusionMatrix(h2o.performance(models[[i]],valid=T))
```

but it generates NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Getting the Mean Squared Error**

To get the Mean Squared Error (MSE) value, you can use the `h2o.mse()` function, as in the following example (Aiello, Kraljevic, & Maj, 2015):

```
perf <- h2o.performance(model = your_data_file.gbm, data = your_data_file.hex)
your_new_variable <- h2o.mse(perf)
```

**Example Results**

```
> h2o.performance(model = your_data_file.gbm, data = your_data_file.hex)
H2OBinomialMetrics: gbm
** Reported on training data. **

MSE:  0.07584147
R^2:  0.6846763
LogLoss:  0.2744668
AUC:  0.9780312
Gini:  0.9560623

> perf <- h2o.performance(model = your_data_file.gbm, data = your_data_file.hex)
> your_new_variable <- h2o.mse(perf)
> your_new_variable
[1] 0.07584147
```

**About the Confusion Matrix**

Also, the NULL value from your *confusion matrix* might indicate that your `h2o.performance()` function itself does not contain or return a confusion matrix.

---

**References**

Aiello, S., Kraljevic, T., & Maj, P. (2015, November 24). Package ‘h2o’. Retrieved December 2, 2015, from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf